# Partitions on Message-Hub Service from Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

I know there isn't this feature yet but, Will it be provided in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean multiple partitions on a single topic? Right now Message Hub only allows a single partition per topic. This restriction will remain for some time once we exit Beta as well, but we do aim to allow a flexible number of partitions per topic in the future, although we do not have a date for when this will be available yet.

Answer (score 2):

Now is possible to create multiple partitions for a topic. There is a limit of 100 partitions per each Bluemix space. To create more partitions, is necessary to use a new Bluemix space. It's important to mention that all those partitions (100) could be divided among different topics.
e.g. if we have 5 topics in that instance/space, the total sum of partitions should be 100 (max) divided between those 5 topics